# React-native IOS .ipa build fails

Tags: ios, reactjs, react-native, ipa

I'm trying to build a .ipa file for IOS in react-native.

I ran `npx react-native run-ios --configuration Release`

It builds up to a point and then fails, the first error I had was:

```
The following build commands failed:
        CompileC /Users/admin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/...-avqlzugdfpvrcddddqfvfjatmvtp/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Release-iphonesimulator/react-native-ffmpeg.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/RNExecuteDelegate.o /Users/admin/bookit-rn/ios/Pods/react-native-ffmpeg/ios/RNExecuteDelegate.m normal x86_64 objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
(1 failure)

npm notice 
npm notice New minor version of npm available! 8.1.2 -> 8.3.0
npm notice Changelog: https://github.com/npm/cli/releases/tag/v8.3.0
npm notice Run npm install -g npm@8.3.0 to update!
npm notice
```

I notice the error is with the `react-native-ffmpeg`, then I made some changes and ran the build command again.

And this time it didn't return `react-native-ffmpeg`, but returned another error:

```
The following build commands failed:
    Ld /Users/admin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/GLibraryRN-avqlzugdfpvrcddddqfvfjatmvtp/Build/Intermediates.noindex/GLibraryRN.build/Release-iphonesimulator/GLibraryRN.build/Objects-normal/arm64/Binary/GLibrary\ Sports normal arm64
(1 failure)
```

Seems it has something to do with DerivedData. Please do you have any idea what this issue is and how it can be fixed?

Comment: Did you tried to delete the derived data and then build again?

Comment: No, I haven't tried that. So I will follow this part: /Users/admin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/

and delete this folder - DerivedData/?